# AngularJS app loading old resources on live server, localhost is fine

Tags: angularjs, caching, twitter-bootstrap-3, digital-ocean

I have a MEAN app in production on Digital Ocean, but have observed strange behavior when recently migrating a new Bootstrap theme to replace the previous designs. What I've noticed is that even after I replaced the code that included certain elements, such as a background image, the webserver would still be looking for them.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  https://www.website.com/img/frontpage-img.jpg
```

I even grepped from the root directory to ensure frontpage-img.jpg was no longer included anywhere within the codebase, and got

```
Binary file .git/index matches
```

as the only result. This behavior is also not replicated on the localhost, which works exactly as I expect it to. Is this a server-related issue? How do I purge the old elements to prevent the server from trying to load them?

Comment: try clearing the cache on **your** browser. it could be that the browser cached the old index and is still requesting old resources. in devtools you can turn off caching completely.